# Sharepoint Crawl from internal portal Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have set my Sharepoint to "only crawl within the server of each start address" . I already put the address in start address box . but when i try to using search function in my portal, it still crawls the unnecessary things of external portal.. What is the correct way to crawl things within the portal only?

Comment: Internal and external are two different site/ web application? What  other things it crawl? What are ur portal setups?

Comment: I am not sure how the search is handling the deletion of items, when changing the start address. Can you verify , if the sites you don't want in the search results, were crawled by checking the last crawl logs.